# Taking $\min$ inside summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization

Suppose $f: I\times J \to [0, 1]$ where $I, J$ are finite.
Consider $\alpha = \min_{i \in I}\left(\sum_{j \in J} f(i,j)\right)$ and $\beta = \sum_{j \in J}\left(\min_{i \in I} f(i,j)\right)$.
What is the relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: $\beta \leq \alpha$ but the inequality can be strict.

Comment: As a hint, try to establish the inequality $$\beta \leq \sum_{j\in J}f(i,j)$$ for *any* $i\in I$.

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint by @SangchulLee:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta &= \sum_{j \in J} \min_{i \in I} f(i,j)\\
&\le \sum_{j \in J} f(i,j) \hspace{1em} \text{for all $i$, as $f(i,j) \ge \min_{i\in I}f(i, j)$ for all $i$}\\
&\le \min_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} f(i,j) = \alpha \hspace{1em} \text{as the previous inequality holds for all $i$}
\end{aligned}
$$